# Proving that (simple) regression can estimate average treatment effect if a covariate is binary

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to prove we can use regression to estimate average causal effect if a covariate is binary and a randomized treatment.

In other words, I want to prove the following.

\begin{align}
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(X_i - \bar{X})}{ \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2 } = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i (1-X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-X_i)} \ \cdots (1)
\end{align}

This makes sense if we consider the following regression model.
$$
Y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \varepsilon_i,
$$
because 
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y_i | X_i = 0] = \alpha
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y_i | X_i = 1] = \alpha + \beta
$$
so, average treatment effect is 
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{E}[Y_i(1) - Y_i(0)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y_i(1) | X_i = 1] - \mathbb{E}[Y_i(0) | X_i = 1] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y_i(1) | X_i = 1] - \mathbb{E}[Y_i(0) | X_i = 0]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y_i | X_i = 1] - \mathbb{E}[Y_i | X_i = 0]\\
&= \beta
\end{align}

But I want to get the right-hand side of (1) from its left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = a$, $\sum_{i=1}^nY_i = b$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i = c$. As all $X_i$ are binary, then also $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = a$ and $\bar{X}=a/n$.

It is easy to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2 = a(n-a)/n = k$.

Then, the $LHS = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(X_i - \bar{X})\right)/k= (c-ab/n)/k=(nc-ab)/[a(n-a)]$.

Similarly, the $RHS = c/a - (b-c)/(n-a)= (cn-ab)/[a(n-a)]$

Admittedly, this does not show how to transform $LHS$ into $RHS$ but at least proves that they are equal.